# firing function from Google sign in button when user is already signed into browser

Tags: javascript, google-signin

I am trying to have a Google Sign in on my website.

At present if you are already signed into the browser the button will say 'signed in' and the `g_login()` function will fire.

If you are not signed into the browser, it will say 'sign in' and clicking on it will fire the `onSignIn()` function which will then sign you in. In this case you then have to click the button again to fire the `g_login()` function.

How can I get the `g_login()` function to fire after the `onSignIn()` function if the button is clicked but not fired automatically without a user clicking on the button if they are already signed into the browser?

```
function onSignIn(googleUser){
    g_profile = googleUser.getBasicProfile();
}
function g_login(){
    var user_id = g_profile.getId();
    var user_name = g_profile.getName();
    var user_email = g_profile.getEmail();
    
    //do stuff
}

<div class="g-signin2" data-onsuccess="onSignIn" onclick="g_login();">
```

Comment: So calling g_login() inside onSignIn() doesn't work? Does onSignIn() trigger an asynchronous call?

Comment: yeah so if i call g_login() inside onSignIn() it will automatically happen straight away if the user is logged into the browser without any interaction or clicking the button, but i need them to actually click the button first

Comment: Oh my bad... You can try creating a global boolean variable and checking that variable before firing g_login(). And only clicking on the button will make that boolean true.

Comment: that would leave the same problem as i'd have no way to change the boolean without firing the onclick function first to actually update the boolean

Comment: Just to be clear, you want it that if you're already signed in you still need to click the button and presumably do navigation to somewhere else? And if you're not signed in clicking the button calls onSignIn and once that's done calls the g_login function?

Comment: Use a custom event - `window.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('g_login_event')` and set a listener for that custom event to fire the `g_login` function.

Comment: @mancony that is correct

Comment: @mmason33 could you point me to some documentation for that?

Comment: I'm not quite sure if this will work. But, you can check for when a cookie is being set in the browser for the user's session. If the cookie is set, you can automatically fire the g_login() function, when it is not don't fire it. This can work in both circumstances that you've mentioned. But, again. I'm not sure because I haven't worked with Google's Auth API.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use `SignIn()` (don't forget to update`@@CLIENT_ID@@`) :

```
 gapi.load('auth2', function() {
  auth2 = gapi.auth2.init({
    client_id: '@@CLIENT_ID@@',
    fetch_basic_profile: false,
    scope: 'profile'
  });

  // Sign the user in, and then call g_login
  auth2.signIn().then(function() {
    g_login();
  });
});
```